# random number different output every time

Tags: java, random, unique

I am coding a secret santa program that prints out the unique secret santa of all participants and does not repeat the output on same input.

My problems are:

1. The program is generating same output on some reruns...
2. The program hangs after first run if more than or equal to 3 names present in the list. It prints correct output for only a few entries. For e.g. 3 names it prints secret santas of 2 names and hangs!

The code is as follows.

```
    SecretSanta ss=new SecretSanta();
    Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);

    do
    {
        System.out.println("Add the participants name:-");
        String name=scn.next().trim();
        ss.names.add(name);
        ss.santa.add(name);
        System.out.println("Do u want to add more names?");
        System.out.println(" 1-YES 2-NO");
        choice=scn.nextInt();           
    }while(choice==1);

    do
    {
        total_size=ss.santa.size();
        System.out.println(total_size);
        Collections.shuffle(ss.santa);
        System.out.println(ss.names.size());
        System.out.println("Below is the list of participants with their secret santas");
        Iterator<?> itr=ss.names.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            String name=(String)itr.next(); 
            String SecretName;
            do
            {
            int rand=r.nextInt(total_size);
            SecretName=ss.santa.get(rand);
            }while(name.equals(SecretName));

            System.out.println(name+"    "+SecretName); 
            ss.santa.remove(SecretName);
            total_size=ss.santa.size();     
        }
        ss.santa.addAll(ss.names);
        Collections.shuffle(ss.santa);
        System.out.println("do you want to rerun??");
        System.out.println(" 1-YES 2-NO");
        choice=scn.nextInt();
    }while(choice==1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can never be sure that a configuration does not repeat. There are just 6 permutations of 3 elements, so each 6th rerun (statistically) the configuration would repeat, assuming that you have 3 items in the list.

Next, about your hangs. You are removing items from the list, and then ask the program to find an element there. Imagine this situation: your names are Fred, Eric, Mike. The choices are

```
Fred - Eric
Eric - Fred
```

So you get only Mike in the list and only Mike in the list of santas. See the problem? There is no way to choose a santa. This can be solved in a few ways.

The most simple way is to shuffle names, assume that they are corresponding by indices and check whether anybody is santa for himself. If so, reshuffle. This still has the mentioned problem, but just for the list size one (in which case the problem obviously unsolvable).

Comment: I do not want different outputs on each run but only on consecutive runs . I added the following code

while(itr.hasNext())
  {
   String name=(String)itr.next(); 
   String SecretName;
   do
   {
   int rand=r.nextInt(total_size);
   SecretName=ss.santa.get(rand);   
   }while(name.equals(SecretName) || s.contains(SecretName) );
   s.add(SecretName);
   System.out.println(name+"    "+SecretName);   
  }
  
  s.removeAll(ss.names);

Answer (score 0):

The program is generating same output on some reruns because u are using random function and that function can produce repeated numbers (**int rand=r.nextInt(total_size);**).